# Python car race winner

Tags: python, class, loops, python-3.x

I need to create a Python program that will determine the winner of a race using the equation `odometer_miles = odometer_miles + speed * time` and with a class called `Car` that has "total odometer miles", "speed", "driver name", and "sponsor" attributes.

The `speed` variable is a number between 0 and 120 (mph) that is generated randomly every minute.  The equation is then performed again, updating the `odometer_miles` variable.

Once an `odometer_miles` variable reaches 500 (or the closest value greater than 500) miles, the race is over, and whichever racer (out of a group of 20) reaches 500 is declared the winner.  When the winner is determined, the program needs to print the "driver name" and "sponsor".

I think I have the class created properly, but the rest of the program is far beyond my capabilities.  My textbook is less than useless, and I have no way to contact my professor.  I've spent the past several hours trying to figure it out to no avail.

This is what I have so far:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, odo_miles, speed, driver, sponsor):
        self.odo_miles = odo_miles
        self.speed = speed
        self.driver = driver
        self.sponsor = sponsor
```

If someone could show me how to do it with just two racers or enough that I can fill in for the full 20 racers required, I would be eternally grateful.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This car class should have everything you need, note that the order in which you increment the racers will matter. Anyways, from here you can create a list/set of cars, and then loop through it, applying updateMinute() to each one until you have a winner. You can break out of the loop when updateMinute() returns True, and use the car that you currently updated to find the driver and sponsor.

```
import random
class Car:

    def __init__(self, odo_miles, speed, driver, sponsor):
        self.odo_miles = odo_miles
        self.speed = speed
        self.driver = driver
        self.sponsor = sponsor

    def updateMinute():
        self.odo_miles += speed              #I'm updating the distance before newSpeed
                                             #So that the original speed passed in is used
        if self.odo_miles > 500:
            return True
        self.speed = random.randrange(120)
        return False
```

To run through the list:

```
while True:
    for c in cars:
        finished = c.updateMinute()
        if finished:
            print_relevant_stuff()
            return
```

Comment: I would move the update of self.speed after the "return True".

Comment: Done, but it doesn't matter much. Its one operation that you'll end up saving once. (when the car wins).

Comment: Yes, but this way you can still know what the last speed was. Otherwise you end up with an instance whose speed value was never used.

Comment: How would I have updateMinute() run through my list?  I'm assuming I would do something with a `while` loop right?  Sorry if this is a stupid question.  I'm trying to fit a 15 week course into 5 weeks and it's a bit overwhelming.

Comment: @user2466838: I edited my OP answering that.